# AUTOSAR implementation rules?

Tags: autosar

I just stumbled over a document from Autosar 4.0 release, which specifies some implementation rules:
[Specification of C Implementation Rules](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/4-0/AUTOSAR_TR_CImplementationRules.pdf)
It's mentioned in the Rev. History of 4.0, but it doesn't seem to be part of any succeeding release.
Did I miss something? Are these rules still valid or not?

Answer (score 1):

I've work with lots of developers writing C code, and using static analysis tools for checking various coding guidelines. It depends entirely on who the customer is for the software being written.

If you are a supplier for an OEM, they will provide guidance as to rules to follow.  If you work at an OEM, your software process team should have guidance for you.   Anyone with whom I've discussed coding guidelines, that is doing Classic AUTOSAR (instead of Adaptive AUTOSAR which is C++14) is generally just following the MISRA C:2012 ruleset, per their OEM requirements.

I've not met anyone that cares about AUTOSAR outside of the automotive industry, unless they are writing C++ code, in which case they are treating the AUTOSAR C++14 rule set as they would MISRA C:2012 - a well vetted coding guideline that is useful across industries.